# Почему медали нет в оповещениях на ru.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: дефект

На других проектах я вижу в оповещениях полученные медали.
А тут на `ru.stackoverflow.com` почему-то нет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть из картинки:

- я получил медаль "Организатор".
- Медаль отобразилась в статистике (до этого было 7 медалей)
- Видим, что медаль была выдана 27 мин назад

А вот в достижениях почему-то этой информации нет.

---

Кажется и для `stackoverflow.com` данная награда не оповещается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя другие медальки работают нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]